# setup file for one solution and several projects

Tags: c#

In my windows app in C#,I have one solution containing three projects. one of them is startup project and has references to others. now I want to create setup file, but I don't know how do it. I used the way i used to one solution with one project but after installation, the application didn't execute and couldn't use the other two projects,

Comment: have you tried using Click Once deployment ?

Comment: no, I don't know it, how can I do it?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=D_I2Vru7M4iFoAOx4aMg#q=clickonce%20deployment

Comment: what was the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code in Debug to Release mode.then u got a application file.

Comment: excuse me, I don't underestand your answer, please explain more, I created setup file with setup projetc in c# and it didn't execute

Comment: my startup project's name is main_program and my second project's name is indexing_program. in main_program when user clicks a picturebox, indexing_program opens. after installing the file, when i click picturebox, it gives an exception that couldn't load or assembly indexing_program or one of its dependencies